# Paypal IPN fix regular expression

Tags: php, paypal

I am new to paypal I found the code mentioned below but unable to understand it can anyone explain it to me? Thanks in anticipation

Transaction comes from PayPal & I here its checking its IPN RESPONSE

```
function verifyTransaction($data) {
    global $paypalUrl;

    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i', '${1}%0D%0A${3}', $value); // IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
```

I am unable to understand this line of code

```
$value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i', '${1}%0D%0A${3}', $value); // IPN fix
```

Comment: [preg_replace() manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: [Looking for a regex tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=regex+tutorial)

Comment: Its fixing line endings to be `0D0A` (newline carriage return) regardless of which line terminator was used on the original data